# How to drop a partition from BigQuery table using standard sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

delete from table_name where _PARTITIONTIME = (condition) is not needed as delete/update has quota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not yet, and your condition is time based - you should consider setting [`partition expiration`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#timePartitioning.expirationMs)

More options (still depends on your use case):

- `copy` partition by partition into new table with append (free of charge operation but have similar quota "issue" as DML per project, whereas much better quota for per table - );
- `create table from select` with respective conditions (full table scan - respective cost)