# How to Drop the partition column from big query table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried to drop the created partition in bq please find the below query I have used as I am new to BQ and please correct me with right syntax

Confirm if drop partition is acceptable or not in BQ

```
DROP PARTITION data_set.table_name.Partitioned_column_name
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to drop a partition from BigQuery table using standard sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49427052/how-to-drop-a-partition-from-bigquery-table-using-standard-sql)

Comment: I'm little bit confused because you used `data_set.table_name.Partitioned_column_name` in your syntax. Are you pretending to drop a column? or you want to use `Partitioned_column_name` as condition to delete some particular partition?